# nothing show up win using File Opener in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework

I read the document from Ionic Document https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener/

but win i try to use this plugin in android emulator, nothing show up

this is my html code :

```
<ion-content padding class="background">
<div>
  <button ion-button (click)="openpdf()">pdf</button>
</div>
```

and this is typeScript code:

```
openpdf(){

this.fileOpener.open('assets/filepdf.pdf', 'application/pdf')
 .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
 .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
 }
```

win i click the button nothing happens!

Comment: your path is wrong.

Comment: i put the "filepdf.pdf" inside the assets folder

Comment: I think Relative paths are not supported. you have to use https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have proper file in assets/filepdf.pdf?

You can see error messages like: missing file, access denied or other problems by using for example alert component (it is dirty but works on devices of emulators without additional debugging)

```
export class MyPage {

  constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController) { }

openpdf(){

 this.fileOpener.open('assets/filepdf.pdf', 'application/pdf')
  .then(() => 
{
       console.log('File is open', e));

       const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
           title: 'File is open',
           subTitle: "",
           buttons: ['OK']
       });
       alert.present();
     }
   )
  .catch(e => 
     {
       console.log('Error opening file', e));

       const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
           title: 'Error',
           subTitle: e,
           buttons: ['OK']
       });
       alert.present();
     }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

check  this Example in this PDF will be download(FileTransfer pluign) and open:

```
 downloadAndOpenPdf(name) {
    let path = null;

    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      path = this.file.documentsDirectory;
    } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      path = this.file.dataDirectory;
    }

    const transfer = this.transfer.create();
    transfer.download(globalData.imagesUrl + name, path + 'myfile.pdf').then(entry => {
      let url = entry.toURL();
      this.document.viewDocument(url, 'application/pdf', {});
    });
  }
```